# Changing SSH Port: Should I modify only sshd_config, or also ssh_config?

Tags: linux, ssh, configuration

I would like to change my SSH port running Linux CentOS 6.

From what I've read on forums, people recommend changing my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file to use a different port number, then restarting the SSHD service.

I also noticed there's an `ssh_config` file along with `sshd_config`.  What's the difference between the two?  Should I change both?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The `sshd_config` is the ssh ***daemon*** (or ssh server process) configuration file. As you've already stated, this is the file you'll need to modify to change the server port.

Whereas, the `ssh_config` file is the ssh ***client*** configuration file. The client configuration file only has bearing on when you use the `ssh` command to connect to another ssh host.  So, in this case, you don't need to modify it.  It will be *other* client machines connecting to your server.